# UIScrollView Crashes the app when swiping after image 10

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I've created an image gallery and I've got it all working with low res images as I understand that if you use too many high res it crashes my app. The problem I'm now facing is that when the user clicks on an image, after swiping around 9-10 images it crashes the app. What is the best practice to stop this happening?

Here's my load page function where I believe this problem could be:

```
func loadPage(page: Int) {

        if page < 0 || page >= arrGallery.count {
            // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
            return
        }

        if let page = pageViews[page] {
            // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
        } else {
            var frame = scrollView.bounds
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
            frame.origin.y = 0.0

            let rowData: NSDictionary = arrGallery[page] as! NSDictionary
            let urlString: String = rowData["pic"] as! String
            let imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
            // If this image is already cached, don't re-download
            if let img = imageCache[urlString] {
                let newPageView = UIImageView(image: img)
                newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                newPageView.frame = frame
                scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)


                pageViews[page] = newPageView
            }
            else {
                // The image isn't cached, download the img data
                // We should perform this in a background thread
                let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!)
                let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        // Store the image in to our cache

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.imageCache[urlString] = image
                            // Update the cell
                            let newPageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                            newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                            newPageView.frame = frame
                            self.scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)

                            // 4
                            self.pageViews[page] = newPageView
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
            }

        }
```

The crash i receive is:

> 2016-05-11 13:28:58.743 The Britannia[19024:7909175] Received memory
>   warning.

Thank you!

Updated:

I've implemented lazy loading on the images with SDWebImage as to your answer and the new code is:

```
func loadPage(page: Int) {

        if page < 0 || page >= arrGallery.count {
            // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
            return
        }

        if let page = pageViews[page] {
            // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
        } else {
            var frame = scrollView.bounds
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
            frame.origin.y = 0.0

            let rowData: NSDictionary = arrGallery[page] as! NSDictionary
            let urlString: String = rowData["pic"] as! String
            let imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
            // If this image is already cached, don't re-download
            if let img = imageCache[urlString] {
                let newPageView = UIImageView(image: img)
                newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                newPageView.frame = frame
                scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)


                pageViews[page] = newPageView
            }
            else {


                SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadImageWithURL(imgURL, options: [],progress: nil, completed: {[weak self] (image, error, cached, finished, url) in

                    if error == nil {

                     //   let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        //On Main Thread
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                            self!.imageCache[urlString] = image
                                                        // Update the cell
                                                        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                                                        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                                                        newPageView.frame = frame
                                                        self!.scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)

                                                        // 4
                                                        self!.pageViews[page] = newPageView
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    })
            }
            return

        }

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of crash? What line does it crash on? Best practice would be using a debugger, I think.

Comment: I think that crash is because of memory leak. And if it is then Why don't you use concept of lazy loading. It will help you to manage memory in application.

Comment: Exactly.  Make sure "Enable zombies" is enabled in your Xcode, and find out where the code is crashing.

Comment: Sorry I've added the crash report.

Comment: @RobertMellor , As I told you try lazy loading concept. To load images you can use SDWebImage library to cache and load image effectively.